# How to make a live PHP form?

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

I want to know how to make a live PHP page, i.e., it does not refresh/load when we submit details of a form.

Examples where it is used:

1. Stack Overflow (while submitting post)
2. Facebook (while updating status) On facebook, the status is published and the page is not reloaded.

I want to know which language I must learn/use to create such form pages.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I may have use wrong words. Please help me.

Comment: The spotters guide for *help vamps*: http://www.slash7.com/pages/vampires

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this easy with Javascript/JQuery

**Example:**

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script> 
var auto_refresh = setInterval(
function()
{
$('#loaddiv').fadeOut('slow').load('reload.php').fadeIn("slow");
}, 20000);
</script>
```

It is loading the 'reload.php' file into the div id 'loaddiv' every 20000 ms -> 20 sec.
DIV:

```
<div id="loaddiv"> 
</div>
```

And then edit the 'reload.php' file.

Good luck!

Comment: How do we do it? What is Javascript.Jquery? Does it mean Javascrit and Jquery?

Comment: Hi, i edited my post with a example code.

Comment: Which method i need to use with it ? Get or Post?

Comment: Check out the answer of Enam -> http://stackoverflow.com/a/14044193/1234583

Answer (score 3):

Try the following code:

```
<form id="myForm" action="comment.php" method="post"> 
    Name: <input type="text" name="name" /> 
    Comment: <textarea name="comment"></textarea> 
    <input type="submit" value="Submit Comment" /> 
</form>

<html> 
<head> 
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.js"></script> 
    <script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js"></script> 

    <script> 
        // wait for the DOM to be loaded 
        $(document).ready(function() { 
            // bind 'myForm' and provide a simple callback function 
            $('#myForm').ajaxForm(function() { 
                alert("Thank you for your comment!"); 
            }); 
        }); 
    </script> 
</head> 
...
```

Codes are taken form [THIS Link](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/).

Comment: And what if i need to show the comment on the same page. It's just showing an alert. I need the comment above it.

Comment: Replace the alert() with your Success Code (i.e. show user comment etc).

Comment: I want the comment/message to be showed below it. How to do it?

Comment: Please check this link http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#ajaxForm

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29).

[jQuery has a good AJAX engine](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).